# ~/.bashrc changes have no effect?

Tags: bash, bashrc, prompt

I have been trying to set some custom colors on the `user@hostname:~$` on the terminal. I edited both `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Where it said:

```
debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot...
```

I just changed it to:

```
debian_chroot:::::::+($debian_chroot
```

To see if the changes had any effect, but it rebooted and the terminal still looks like the default.

What am I doing wrong? I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: If that's what it looks like, you changed the middle of an unrelated variable expansion in a way that won't do anything visible to normal accounts.  Do you normally change random stuff in random ways in your dotfiles, ignoring the possibility that the wrong random thing might leave you unable to log in or unable to open a terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:
Pay attention that after the line `if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then` there are two options: one if the line `force_color_prompt=yes` is commented and another - if it isn't. Make sure to change the right one.

Then:
You are changing the wrong place at the line. The complete line would be something like:
    `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '`.

So the change you mean is something like:
    `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:::::::\w\$ '`

*(NOT:     `PS1='${debian_chroot::::+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '`)*